# Rails, SQLException: no such column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

After rechecking the code, restarting my computer, and running rake db:migrate, I'm not sure what else to do with this. I keep getting the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: uploads.user_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "uploads"  WHERE "uploads"."user_id" = 1

Extracted source (around line #12):

9:     </section>
10:   </aside>
11:   <div class="span8">
12:     <% if @user.uploads.any? %>
13:       <h3>Uploads (<%= @user.uploads.count %>)</h3>
14:       <ol class="uploads">
15:         <%= render @uploads %>
```

Does this have anything to do with the has_many association?

**show.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
<aside class="span4">
<section>
  <h1>
    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
    <%= @user.name %>
  </h1>
</section>
</aside>
<div class="span8">
<% if @user.uploads.any? %>
  <h3>Uploads (<%= @user.uploads.count %>)</h3>
  <ol class="uploads">
    <%= render @uploads %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @uploads %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

**upload.rb**

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :title

belongs_to :user

validates :title, presence: true
validates :user_id, presence: true

default_scope order: 'uploads.created_at DESC'
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
has_secure_password
has_many :uploads, dependent: :destroy

before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
before_save :create_remember_token

validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence:   true,
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

private

def create_remember_token
  self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
end
```

**from users_controller.rb**

```
  def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @uploads = @user.uploads.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

**20120524145724_create_uploads.rb**

```
class CreateUploads < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
create_table :uploads do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.integer :user_id

  t.timestamps
  end
  add_index :uploads, [:user_id, :created_at]
end

def self.down
drop_table :uploads
end
end
```

Comment: Did you add user_id to the migration after you had already run in once?

Comment: yes, I did. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a migration is run, rails won't rerun it if you update it (it doesn't know what changes you made).

Either roll the migration back (rake db:rollback) before you edit it or create a new migration that adds the extra columns.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations may fail somethimes, if you have some errors on it for example it wont work. Make sure it did run and you could check your sqlite db to see if there is a user_id or not