# no such column: user_id error rails pagination of friends

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model that has many Friends. I'm trying to paginate the friends but I'm receiving a no such column error. The solution seems to be answered here [Rails, SQLException: no such column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745671/rails-sqlexception-no-such-column) but I just don't  understand that answer enough.

Can someone please help me explan what is wrong and how to fix it?

in my home.html.erb

```
<div class="span8">
    <ol class="friends">
            <%= render @friends %>
        </ol>
        <%= will_paginate @friends %>
</div>
```

in my _friends partial:

```
<li>
    <span class="friendname"><%= friend.name %></span>
    <span class="friendid"><%= friend.friendid %></span>
</li>
```

controller

```
def home
    @friends = current_user.friends.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Current_user is defined in a sessions_helper as:

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

friend model

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :friendid, :name, :uid
    belongs_to :user
    validates :uid, presence: true
    validates :friendid, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :provider, :uid
   has_many :friends, dependent: :destroy
   validates :uid, presence:true, uniqueness:true
   .
   .
   .
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this question, friend model is looking for user_id as the key that associates the two models. you can set the primary key in any model by typing `self.primary_key = 'name of column'` and then set the column to look for in the second model with `foreign_key=>'name of column from second model'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add column named user_id to your table. To do it, you must create migration and run it.

Comment: Why is there even a column user_id required?

Comment: "belongs_to :user"
So, you must have user_id column in friend.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Ah thank you for the link. Based on that, would `:foreign_key => "uid",
    :association_foreign_key => "uid"` in my user model fix my error? I'm assuming this connects the uid from User model (foreign key) to the uid from my Friend's model (associative foreign key). Is that right?

Comment: You have to try it. 
But why don't you want to add this column? It's easier.

Comment: it didn't work...I don't want to add that column because rails does a lot of behind the scenes action and I'd like to understand what is happening. It's a bit confusing that I can't associate the two tables by simply choosing which column represents the key that ties them together. I tried :foreign_key=>"uid" on both models but to no avail

Comment: Sorry, but I can't look on it now. 
Usually, I do all as in the examples for my association type and it's working. 
Look carefully on options that you are passing through and on association type, that you are using.